# why Ransomware malware payment message not encrypted also?

Tags: encryption, malware

it is an awkward question but just want to know why the payment message not encrypted or corrupted or any error seems to happen when pop-up?
and what type of this message is it an excutable extension or something else?

Comment: What would be the point of encrypting the message extorting your money? Can't pay if you can't read it.

Comment: I think if the message, not encrypted there is a way to decrypt a PC

Comment: The message is simply not included in the ransomeware's list of things to encrypt. Something that didn't get encrypted will give no clues whatsoever about how to decrypt anything else. That logical leap is like trying to guess someone's age based on the nationality of their doctor.... utterly unrelated.

Comment: "...  not encrypted there is a way to decrypt a PC" - This does not make sense.  The only way to decrypt the password is if you have the key to do so.  Encrypting or not encrypting the payment message wouldn't change the fact, the only way to get the key, is to provide the payment or for there to be a vulnerability in the ransomware itself that causes the Command and Control server to be compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/users/347380/tetsujin) said, the user needs to:

- Know that he must pay to recover his files;
- Know how to pay.

An encrypted message would be useless for both the hackers and the user.

**How does a (basic) ransomware work?**

You may not understand how a ransomware really works. A basic<sup>1</sup> [ransomwares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware) will encrypt *most* of your files and create a `READ_THIS_TO_GET_YOUR_FILES_BACK.txt` on your desktop. However, it won't encrypt the files needed by your OS as your computer must be able to boot for you to see what is happening.

Imagine you have this file structure:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Victim

.
├── Desktop
│   ├── photo.png
│   └── stuff.txt
├── Documents
│   └── Work
│       ├── contract.pdf
│       ├── another_document.pdf
...
```

Our basic ransomware can decide to only encrypt the files that are in the `C:\Documents and Settings\Victim` directory. To be sure you know what's going on, it will create the file `READ_THIS_TO_GET_YOUR_FILES_BACK.txt` on your desktop.

You will be stuck with a file structure like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Victim

.
├── Desktop
│   ├── photo.png [encrypted]
│   ├── stuff.txt [encrypted]
│   └── READ_THIS_TO_GET_YOUR_FILES_BACK.txt [not encrypted]
├── Documents
│   └── Work
│       ├── contract.pdf [encrypted]
│       ├── another_document.pdf [encrypted]
...
```

To be even more scary, it could rename all your file too to some strange `random_str.bin` names.

As you can see, the creation of that last `.txt` file is totally independent of the encryption used. Nothing about the key used is leaked. It's just a regular file. Encrypting it would be counter-productive. They need you to know that *you have to pay,* and they need you to know *how to pay.*

Think about it like a kidnapping: will you stick your ransom note on your victim, locked in your basement?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is a really basic explanation of how ransomware may work. Some of them will encrypt your whole hard drive; others won't encrypt anything but will still kick you out of your computer. What is certain is that they will all figure out a way to tell you how to pay. They need you to pay.</sup>

<sup>[They also have a great customer service.](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2894507/opensource-subnet/some-cybercriminals-are-improving-customer-service-for-their-victims.html)</sup>